# Where can I find SQL statements to create EAV model?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-modeling, entity-attribute-value

Alternatively, anyone know of where I can get the EAV model for Erwin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would anybody want to build an EAV system using a SQL database?  It's a square peg in a round hole.

If you are really convinced that EAV is the appropriate solution for your problem domain why not choose a database product which supports it?  Cassandra or Voldemort or Dynomite?

Comment: there are still several use cases where EAV database are used, in an RDBMS systems to tailor the needs of Application. I got a requirement in an Oil and Gas industry, where the meters changes names based on the date and other metrics. and for that EAV model was the perfect fit, and worked great. NoSQL is a good option when consider the development process requirements, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

the tables and structure will depend on your domain.

here is information you can use as sample/template - [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-Attribute-Value_model)